# WinAPI Window does not update anymore after taking screenshot with PrintWindow

Tags: c++, winapi, screenshot

I am taking screenshots of an application using [PrintWindow()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-printwindow). The application contains a listview and after some time, the list does not update anymore. Only when I select an entry in the list, does it update the name of that entry. My assumption is that the ListView's window does not get invalidated somehow, but that's just a guess. I tried calling [InvalidateRect()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-invalidaterect) after taking the screenshot, but that doesn't help either.

I thought the reason for this must be a resource leak, but I encapsulated all required resources in a class, that automatically handles releasing them.

```
struct DrawingSurface
{
  DrawingSurface(const DrawingSurface&) = delete;
  DrawingSurface& operator=(const DrawingSurface&) = delete;

  // Window is a custom class, but it's not really important here.
  DrawingSurface(const Window& window)
  : hwnd(window.handle()), pixels(0), windowDC(0), memoryDC(0), bitmap(0), previous(0)
  {
    // Get window size.
    Rect clientRect = window.getClientRect();
    width = clientRect.width();
    height = clientRect.height();
    // Create DCs.
    windowDC = ::GetDC(window.handle());
    if(windowDC == NULL)
      return;
    memoryDC = ::CreateCompatibleDC(windowDC);
    if(memoryDC == NULL)
      return;
    // Create bitmap.
    ZeroMemory(&bitmapInfo, sizeof(BITMAPINFO));
    bitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    bitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biWidth = width;
    bitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight = -height;
    bitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    bitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
    bitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    bitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = width * height * 4;
    bitmap = ::CreateDIBSection(windowDC, &bitmapInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS, (void**)&pixels, 0, 0);
    if(bitmap == NULL)
      return;
    previous = ::SelectObject(memoryDC, bitmap);
  }
  ~DrawingSurface()
  {
    if(windowDC != NULL)
      ::ReleaseDC(hwnd, windowDC);
    if(previous != NULL && previous != HGDI_ERROR && memoryDC != NULL)
      ::SelectObject(memoryDC, previous);
    if(memoryDC != NULL)
      ::DeleteDC(memoryDC);
    if(bitmap != NULL)
      ::DeleteObject(bitmap);
  }
  bool valid() const
  {
    return width * height > 0
        && previous != NULL
        && previous != HGDI_ERROR
        && windowDC != NULL
        && memoryDC != NULL
        && bitmap != NULL;
  }
  int width, height;
  HWND hwnd;
  HDC windowDC;
  HDC memoryDC;
  HBITMAP bitmap;
  RGBQUAD* pixels;
  BITMAPINFO bitmapInfo;
private:
  HGDIOBJ previous;
};
```

I then use this drawing surface to take a screenshot with this function:

```
bool Screenshot::take(const Window& window)
{
  m_width = 0; m_height = 0;
  DrawingSurface surface(window);
  if(!surface.valid())
    return false;
  if(PrintWindow(surface.hwnd, surface.memoryDC, PW_CLIENTONLY) == 0)
    return false;
  if(GdiFlush() == 0)
    return false;
  // Set attributes.
  m_hwnd = surface.hwnd;
  m_width = surface.width;
  m_height = surface.height;
  // Copy pixels.
  m_pixels.resize(surface.width * surface.height, { 0, 0, 0, 0 });
  memcpy(&m_pixels[0], surface.pixels, surface.bitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage);
  return true;
}
```

I don't see where I could leak any resources here. Any other ideas why what I described above might happen?

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: FYI, `previous` can never be `HGDI_ERROR` in your scenario, so there is no point in checking for it. And you should be checking for `previous==null` in your constructor in case `SelectObject()` fails. More importantly, if the constructor does fail, you should throw an exception instead of leaving the class in an unstable state. That would also allow you to get rid of `valid()`.

Comment: Use Task Manager to diagnose handle leaks, add columns for User Objects and GDI Objects.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I'll remove the check for `HGDI_ERROR`. I don't see why I need to check if `SelectObject()` fails, though, because it will return 0 in case of failure. Then `valid()` will return `false`. Throwing an exception is an option, but it doesn't really change the behavior here, does it? I'll do the TaskManager check, thanks.

Comment: I just checked. There are no resource leaks. Any other ideas what could cause this?

Comment: A [mcve] would greatly improve your chances for getting this solved.

Comment: Propably not the cause, but you shouldn't hold on to `windowDC` (and the related `hwnd`). Call `ReleaseDC(window.handle(), windowDC)` at the end of the constructor to safe resources.

Comment: I don't see major problems with the code shown here, so the root of the problem is propably located in the code you don't show..

Comment: Graphical app + weird behaviour after time -> GDI resource leak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the answers. I was able to solve this myself now and the problem really wasn't related to the screenshot function. Instead I had posted a `WM_KEYDOWN` message to the ListView, and forgot to post `WM_KEYUP` as well. This left the ListView in an invalid state and therefore it did not update anymore.

Thanks again for all the answers and especially for helping to verify that there are no resources leaked.